# scrapy image did not download and there is no error message

Tags: python, amazon-s3, scrapy

My situation is that I save my image to amazon s3  with my setting.py

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "xxxxxx"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "xxxxxx"
IMAGES_STORE = "s3://bucketname/image_store/"
```

I got a problem that scrapy info in terminal didn't show error message,
 but the image didn't download to amazon s3 server.

Did anyone met the similar problem that scrapy didn't show error message when download image is missed??

No error uotput so I don't know where to solve the problem

Here is my terminal console like:

```
2014-09-13 05:04:08+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: ImagesPipeline, ShPipeline
2014-09-13 05:04:08+0000 [email5] INFO: Spider opened
2014-09-13 05:04:08+0000 [email5] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-09-13 05:04:08+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
....
2014-09-13 05:04:08+0000 [email5] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.test.com/test/test>
{'image_urls': [u'http://xxx/.jpg'],
 'images': [{'checksum': 'xxx',
             'path': 'full/xxx.jpg',
             'url': 'http://xxx/.jpg'}],
 'link': 'http://www.test.com/',
  }
2014-09-13 05:04:08+0000 [email5] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-09-13 05:04:08+0000 [email5] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 621,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 71214,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'file_count': 1,
 'file_status_count/downloaded': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 12, 1, 33, 33, 611656),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 12, 1, 33, 31, 766911)}
2014-09-12 01:33:33+0000 [email4] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Update my question:

I found that sometimes the terminal didn't show error.and sometimes there is error like this:

```
2014-09-13 05:04:08+0000 [-] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2014-09-13 05:04:08+0000 [-] Unhandled Error
.....
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: how is your `ImagesPipeline` configured? See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html#enabling-your-images-pipeline

Comment: Paste one of the first log lines where it says `Pipelines enabled:`

Comment: My ImagesPipeline is ````'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,```` and I edit My question with ````Pipelines enabled````